# How to sync several application instances without breaking the integrations?

Tags: integration, servicenow, opentext

There is ServiceNow, OpenText and SAP systems which have been integrated across their DTAP environments. (e.g. ServiceNow DEV <-> SAP DEV; OpenText UAT <-> SAP UAT; etc.)

Periodically we clone over sub-production instances to keep them the same as production.

During every clone we have problems with breaking integrations on SAP or OpenText.

These are caused by wrong integration credential or wrong endpoint which were overwritten by Production information.

What is the best practice how to avoid this problem, help with detection?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude specified tables from a clone by adding each table to the list of exclusions in the Clone Profile. This creates new records on the 'clone_data_exclude' table and associates them to the appropriate Profile.

Reference: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/rome-platform-administration/page/administer/managing-data/task/t_ExcludeATableFromCloning.html?cshalt=yes

You could also use post-clone clean up scripts to set the appropriate integration related values after a clone.

Reference: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/rome-platform-administration/page/administer/managing-data/concept/post-clone-cleanup-scripts.html?cshalt=yes